# How to do simple data binding with dom-repeat in Dart+polymer 1.0?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

My brain hurts. (And sorry, I don't know js).

For my simple example/learning curve, in my HTML file I have:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{datalist}}" as="item">
  {{item}}<br>
</template>
```

and in the Dart file:

```
@reflectable
List<String> datalist = new List();

void rebuildDatas() {
  datalist.clear();
  datalist.add('hello');
}
```

which does not show 'hello'. But if I define:

```
@reflectable
List<String> data= ['one','two'];
```

'one' and 'two' ***are*** listed successfully.

How do I do a dynamic update of `data` please?

(`rebuildDatas()` is called of course!)

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Polymer you are using doesn't support compound bindings.
This changed in Polymer 1.2 (JS) or Polymer Dart 1.0.0-rc.5.

The best action is to upgrade; an interim workaround would be to change this binding to span the whole text content of a tag:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{datalist}}" as="item">
  <span>{{item}}<span><br>
  <!-- or   <div>{{item}}<div> -->
</template>
```

You need to use Polymer API to update property values in order for Polymer to recognize the change and update bound values:

```
@property
List<String> datalist = new List();

void rebuildDatas() {
  clear('datalist');
  add('datalist', 'hello');
}
```

See also [Dart Polymer 1.0 - Two-way binding works?](/q/33170456)

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, but when it calls clear(), in _allocateInvocationMirror, the argumentsDescriptor list is [1,1,null]. From "polymer_base.dart" line 336, I see       the 'evaluate:source': warning: line 2 pos 16: unbalanced '[' opens here
JSON.stringify([path, 0, jsElement, null, 2)
               ^
'evaluate:source': error: line 2 pos 44: unbalanced ')'
JSON.stringify([path, 0, jsElement, null, 2). Steve
                                           ^

Comment: Thanks. I note the updated response.  I am using  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.3
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.6
When it calls clear('datalist')    I get Exception: Uncaught Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined
Stack Trace:
#0      JsObject._callMethod (dart:js:678)
#1      JsObject.callMethod (dart:js:618)
#2      HtmlElement&PolymerMixin&PolymerBase.clear (package:polymer_interop/src/polymer_base.dart:332:15)

Comment: Hard to tell. A whole project that allows to reproduce the problem as GitHub repo would be great.

Comment: Yes, of course. :) Will do. (will probably find the problem myself then!) S

Comment: Running short of time. I have a 14kb project zipped. I haven;t uploaded stuff onto Github yet (but I just tried and failed). How can I send a zip? Cheers, S

Comment: Don't know, some file hosting service (Google Drive, ...) and then post a link here.

Comment: Here is the zip. Thanks. www.sekpa.org/twobinding.zip

Comment: In Polymer elements you need to use the `@property` or `@Property()` annotation for properties `@reflectable` is only for functions in Polymer elements and for functions and fields in model classes (non-Polymer element classes used for data-binding). After changing `@reflectable` for `dataList` to `  @property
  List<String> dataList= new List();` your example worked fined. You might also need to change `- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart` to `- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.dart` in your `pubspec.yaml` but I didn't cause problems in your example.